# Outlet Collections

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have a couple of textField outlet collections. I want to move through each collection and add a border to each textField. I can successfully do this one collection at a time. However, I'd like to not have to call the border function separately for each collection.

I have the following outletCollections

```
@IBOutlet var nameCollection: [UITextField]!
@IBOutlet var phoneCollection: [UITextField]!
```

This works for each collection

```
for name in nameCollection { 
    someFunction...
    }
```

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
let collections = [nameCollection, phoneCollection]

for name in collections {
    someFunction...
    }
```

Basically I want to provide a list of collections and have the function performed on each member of each collection.

Comment: What problem do you face, what is the error when you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine your outlet collections:

```
let combinedCollection = nameCollection + phoneCollection
```

For example:

```
extension UITextField
{
    func doSomething()
    {

    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nameCollection: [UITextField]!
    @IBOutlet var phoneCollection: [UITextField]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let combinedCollection = nameCollection + phoneCollection
        for eachField in combinedCollection
        {
            eachField.doSomething()
        }
    }
}
```

This example assumes that each collection has the same type of object.